# Bump function with fixed L1 norm on the Fourier side

Tags: convolution, fourier-transform

Is it possible to find a function $f$ which is smooth, compactly supported, identically $1$ in a neighborhood of $0$, and such that $\|\hat{f}\|_{L^1} = 1$?

This would be very useful in cutting off a convolution, and still obtain strict estimates on the Fourier side. My apologies if this question is naive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are defining $\hat{f}(\xi) = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}{f(x)e^{-2\pi i \xi x}\,dx}$ so that $f(x) = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}{\hat{f}(\xi)e^{2\pi i \xi x}\,d\xi}$ for $f$ nice enough (or some definition where you can obtain $\|f\|_{L^{\infty}}\le\|\hat{f}\|_{L^1}$):

The answer is no. Indeed, if we assume $\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}{|\hat{f}(\xi)|\,d\xi} = 1$, and that for some $x$ we have $1 = f(x) = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}{\hat{f}(\xi)e^{2\pi i \xi x}\,d\xi}$, then we would have
$$ 0 = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}{|\hat{f}(\xi)|-\hat{f}(\xi)e^{2\pi i \xi x}\,d\xi}. $$
In particular, the real part must vanish. But
$$\text{Re}(\hat{f}(\xi)e^{2\pi i \xi x})\le |\hat{f}(\xi)|,$$
with equality if and only if $\hat{f}(\xi)e^{2\pi i \xi x} = |\hat{f}(\xi)|$. It follows that $|\hat{f}(\xi)|-\text{Re}(\hat{f}(\xi)e^{2\pi i \xi x})\ge 0$ for all $\xi$, and hence
$$ 0 = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}{|\hat{f}(\xi)|-\text{Re}(\hat{f}(\xi)e^{2\pi i \xi x})\,d\xi}\implies |\hat{f}(\xi)|-\text{Re}(\hat{f}(\xi)e^{2\pi i \xi x}) = 0\text{ for almost every }\xi.$$
Thus $\hat{f}(\xi) = |\hat{f}(\xi)|e^{-2\pi i \xi x}$ for almost every $\xi$. This cannot hold for two different values of $x$ since $\hat{f}$ is not zero almost everywhere, so in particular this cannot hold on a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: Thank you. I realized based on your answer that it is enough for me take the cross-correlation between a function $\eta$ and itself, $\|\eta\|_{L^2} = 1$ to obtain an $f$ such that $f(0) = \|\hat{f}\|_{L^1} = \|\eta\|_{L^2}^2 = 1$. I suppose this is close to the best you can do.